# Simultaneous Remote Desktop Connections in Windows Server

Tags: windows, rdp, remote, desktop, rds

I would like to remote control the administrator user of my Windows Server 2008 R2 simultaneously from 3 remote computers. To do that, in Group Policy, I disabled "restrict to a single remote desktop session" and I put "limit number of connections" to 3. Then, I restarted the server but it didn't work. When I tried to connect the third remote computer, I got a message saying "select a user to disconnect so that you may login / there are too many users logged in".

I cannot have more than 2 concurrent sessions. I read that I need to buy “CALS” ... I read also somewhere that there are already 5 “CALS” with Windows Server 2008 R2... Honestly, I’m lost and I don’t know what to do!

Please help !

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can have up to two simultaneous administrative connections to a Windows machine simultaneously, as per your license agreement.

Any more than 2 simultaneous sessions requires a terminal services/remote desktop services installation and client access licenses (CALs).

Comment: When we need 3 simultaneous sessions, do we need to pay for 3 CALs or just one ? And where I buy this ?

Comment: Just 1, since you can still have 2 administrative connections even with RDS installed (mstsc /admin) ... you can buy CALs from lots of places... try cdw.com.

Comment: Ok so I install RDS with licensing and host + I activate my server and I add one user CAL to the administrator. That's it ?

Comment: Yes. RDS gives you a grace period of 180 days before you need CALs, so you will have plenty of time.

Comment: And what's the difference between RDS CAL and CAL ? The price is different but there is no explanation ... Thanks again.